# Replacing array value in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

What am I doing wrong here? It's so simple and I'm overlooking something. I'm trying to replace the value of an array key within a foreach loop:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['firstimg'] = '123';
$arr['secondimg'] = '456';
$arr['thirdimg'] = '789';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == 'secondimg') { 
      $value = '000';

    } 

}

print_r($arr);
```

The array is staying the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$value` is scoped to the loop. You need to update the value of `$arr[$key]`.

Alternatively you can declare the loop as follows:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
```

This makes `$value` a reference to the original array value (rather than a copy).

Comment: +1 I'd recommend the `$arr[$key]` approach as using a reference can have wacky results if `$value` is reused after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Should Be :

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == 'secondimg') { 
      $arr['secondimg'] = '000';

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass by refrence,

```
$arr = array();
$arr['firstimg'] = '123';
$arr['secondimg'] = '456';
$arr['thirdimg'] = '789';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == 'secondimg') { 
      $value = '000';

    } 

}

print_r($arr);
```

to

```
$arr = array();
$arr['firstimg'] = '123';
$arr['secondimg'] = '456';
$arr['thirdimg'] = '789';

foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {

    if ($key == 'secondimg') { 
      $value = '000';

    } 

}

print_r($arr);
```